# Angular2. Angular-calendar event cell detail template

Tags: javascript, angular, templates, typescript, calendar

I' using [angular-calendar] from

> github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar

.
My purpose is to insert own template as detail view on event.
I want to achieve similar effect to presented on photo:
***[final effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdza2.png)***
Till now I achieved only working custom formatting tags as returning string. When I typed some html `input` tags as I see after run in `dom` it disappeared.
Here is me  ***[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0eL51ug3AcqqKs7BNFLc?p=preview)*** if you want to see or maybe you've got idea how to solve that issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular sanitizes untrusted values for HTML. If you want to display `input` you should use `DomSanitizer`

```
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable()
export class CustomEventTitleFormatter extends CalendarEventTitleFormatter {
  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    super();
  }

  month(event: CalendarEvent): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<form>
          First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
                      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
              </form>`)
  }
  ...
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/grPcOjPqK1uMDYhBTeNS?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks, however bypassing security isn't the best way for handling things. Maybe there is some elegant way, but I'm still researching.

Comment: You use `innerHTML`. Which elegant way are you searching? :)

Comment: However angular doesn't seem to perform binding. When I tried to invoke some function after (click) on button from component class or even from title-formatter.provider class it simply didn't happen. Instead of submit form data to component form group after submit click it make values visible in URL.

Comment: Angular doesn't compile innerHTML. It won't work. You can create template dynamically or use event delegation